# Thank you for your recovery wishes?

Tags: phrase-request

I was recently sick and my friends sent me recovery "wishes" (messages wishing me a speedy recovery). Is it correct to say to them "thank you for your wishes"? And would this also apply in different contexts? (for example, when someone is wishing you good luck on a job interview, romantic affair, in a competition etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your (kind) support/words...

Comment: related: https://www.joincake.com/blog/thank-you-for-the-well-wishes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to these messages as "recovery wishes" is technically accurate but just not what people say. In this situation it's more common to say, "Thank you for your thoughtful messages" or "Thank you for your kind thoughts." Maybe "thank you for your kind wishes". Or "nice thoughts/messages/wishes".

Comment: Thanks! So would you say "thank you for your nice wishes" could be acceptable?

Comment: @flen Yes, that would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

"Thank you for your wishes" would read strangely.

"Thank you for thinking of me" or "thanks for all your kind messages" would read more naturally.

Comment: Thank you! What if someone writes an email that has a lot of unrelated stuff (for example, work issues) but also a "hope you get better soon!" and you also want to thank the person for that "wish"? Saying "thinking of me" or "kind message" would be a bit strange given the rest of the text being unrelated to it, but is there a way to single out this and say "and thanks for the |recovery-wishes|"?

Comment: "Thank you for your _good_ wishes." _Your wishes_ could refer to something that the other person wants for themself.